# Hadamard product of a symmetric positive definite matrix and an indefinite matrix of rank 2

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that the Schur product theorem says that the Hadamard product of two positive definite matrices is positive definite.

Can anything be said about the definiteness of the Hadamard product of a symmetric positive definite matrix and an indefinite matrix of rank 2. The latter has one negative and one positive eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is positive definite and $B\in M_n(\mathbb R)$ is indefinite. Then the signature of $A\circ B$ can be any pair of integers $(p,q)$ such that $p,q\ge1$ and $p+q\le n$.

That $p,q\ge1$ follows from the fact that $A\circ B$ has at least one negative entry and at least one positive entry on the diagonal. The signature $(p,q)$ is realised by $A=I_n$ and
$$
B=
2\pmatrix{
E_{p\times p}&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0}
-\pmatrix{
E_{p\times p}&E_{p\times q}&0\\
E_{q\times p}&E_{q\times q}&0\\
0&0&0}
=\pmatrix{
E_{p\times p}&-E_{p\times q}&0\\
-E_{q\times p}&-E_{q\times q}&0\\
0&0&0},
$$
where $E_{r,s}$ denotes the $r\times s$ matrix with all elements equal to $1$. We have $A\circ B=I_p\oplus -I_q\oplus0$ here.